# c#, multiple thread open too many database connection

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I have multiple thread processing hundreds of plants info in a c# console app, each involves lots of database operations (sql server 2012), now I end up having 300 connections open at the same time for a single db. and the number of plants are increasing as the business have more data.

Is it possible not to open too many db connection while still process plants simultaneously?

Comment: Can you show some code for how you deal with connections?  At what level do you open and close your connections (globally, class, or method)?

Comment: I open connection in thread method and close it, db methods in one thread share one connection, I have 300 thread running  at same time, so I have 300 connection open at same time.